# Handling POST Request

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, web, image-uploading

I'm creating a asynchronous upload element with the javascript code bellow:

```
$("#file-input").change(function(){
    uploadImage(this.files[0]);
});

function uploadImage(imageFileHTMLInput) {
    var xml  = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', cover);
    xml.open('POST', url);
    xml.send(data);
    xml.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xml.readyState === 4) {
            if(xml.status === 200) {
                var response = JSON.parse(xml.responseText);
                // handle response
            } else {
                var error = JSON.parse(xml.responseText);
                // handle error
            }
        }
    };
}
```

How can I handle this post in a Symfony2 server? I need to save this file in the server and return the image url.

**UPDATED:**

I made some changes on my code to works fine. I have change all way to do the upload.

Comment: Do you already have a form which works? I think you should start by creating a form, then adding the Javascript part.

Comment: Can I create the form only in javascript code?

Comment: I think that it's possible to get the data in the controller, but you may lose the benefits of validation if the data is not binded to a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get the data from your POST request in the controller via

```
$request->files->get('your_file_identifier_name');
```

Server side, you'll get an instance of [File](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/File.html)